# Adding MathJax to Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'd like to add MathJax to Tumblr site, although I'm a bit confused as to where to begin.

MathJax doesn't offer documentation for Tumblr, just sites like WordPress and some others.

Answer (score 6):

MathJax is now available through a CDN, so you don't have to install it on a server any more. All you need to do is include a few lines in your html header and you can start using mathematics in your posts.

To do this, go to Theme -> Use custom HTML, and insert the following just above the `</head>` marker:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js"></script>
```

Save changes, and you're ready to include mathematics on your Tumblr pages. Try, for example

```
\[ \exp(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \]
```

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Is it sufficient to just copy and paste that first line? Or are we supposed to replace http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML with something else? I attempted to do this on tumblr, and the text post only displayed the raw TeX code.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the MathJax install notes it appears all you need to do is link to the JavaScript file.

For Tumblr, this means you will need to [customize your HTML Theme.](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)

From what I can gather you will need to add this line just before the `</head>` tag.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>`

Where `path-to-MathJax` is to where ever on your server you have uploaded the JS file.

e.g.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Tumblr site</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - The issue I think, I that I'm hosting through tumblr - I just pointed by domain there.  I think I may trying just customizing the HTML with the whole Mathjax source, then try.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Barry's answer, you need to add some additional data to let Tumblr know what to do with the '$' and '$$' that you typically use with MathJax.  Try adding these lines after what's posted above.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
tex2jax: {
  inlineMath: [[ '$','$']],
  displayMath:  [['$$','$$']],
  processEscapes: true
},
"HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
});
</script>
```

[props to http://blog.angjookanazawa.com/post/15081007922/how-to-write-in-latex-use-mathjax-in-tumblr] for providing these.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have enabled the latest MathJax (version 3) on my Tumblr site<sup>[1]</sup> in the following way:

We need to go to the HTML editor of the Tumblr theme template (`Edit appearance → Edit Theme → Edit HTML`) and insert the below MathJax JS script inside the Header tag (somewhere between `<head>` and `</head>`):

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<script>
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [ ['$','$'],['\\(','\\)'] ],
    displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['\\[','\\]'] ],
    processEscapes: true,      
    processEnvironments: true, 
    processRefs: true       
  },
  options: {
   ignoreHtmlClass: 'tex2jax_ignore|editor-rich-text'
  }
};
</script>
```

The same script<sup>[2]</sup> can be applied on WordPress or Blogger<sup>[3]</sup> themes.

Also, there exists a MathJax Configuration Converter<sup>[4]</sup>. This tool can convert a MathJax version 2 configuration to a corresponding MathJax version 3 configuration. So, it can be very useful if anyone wants to do the update automatically.

---

[1] https://rafisics.tumblr.com/post/648704355473752064/mathjax 
[2] https://gist.github.com/rafisics/1babbb8c3ac1d43f595414ec2aa7681a 
[3] https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153527/196564 
[3] https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/convert-configuration/convert-configuration.html